# How to include a LaTeX paper into another LaTeX paper in OverLeaf?

Tags: latex, tex

I have LaTeX paper that I need to include in my dissertation. I am working in OverLeaf. That paper was written under one document class while the university has its own class. I need to include the paper in the dissertation so that it has the university style, its images need to be listed in the list of figures of the dissertation, and the authors listed in the paper's bibliography needs to be listed in the university's class bibliography. Is there any way I can do that in OverLeaf?

Answer (score 2):

There are several dedicated packages for this. For example have a look at the `combine`, `subdocs` or `docmute` packages (A list with even more suggestions can be fond at https://www.ctan.org/recommendations/docmute).

Here a short example with the `docmute` package

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{docmute}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

text

\chapter{imported paper}
\input{test}% assuming your paper is called test.tex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. When I compile, I have the error message that the file I need to input cannot be found, although I can successfully compile that file under its document class.

Answer (score 1):

A Latex document cannot have multiple `\documentclass`. One solution would be to split the header/content of your latex document in overleaf:

- Create a `master.tex` with the documentclass and put all your content (text between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` in a second `content.tex`. In the master, just `\input{content}`.
- In your dissertation, just copy `content.tex`, its figure and add `\input{}` in the master file of your University which has the specific documentclass and bibliography settings.